# Receiving User Input in Lisp

Tags: lisp, sbcl

Just started doing some Lisp a few minutes ago. Trying to figure out why this program won't work properly. I am using SBCL and want to prompt user, read input, then print the statement.

```
(defun SayHello()
    (princ "What is your name? ")
    (let ((name (read))))
    (princ "Hello: ")
    (princ name))
```

When I run this I receive these warnings:

```
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::NAME
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     NAME
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

Comment: Your `let` block is closed immediately- it should include `(princ "Hello: ")` and `(princ name)`. The linked question contains correct code and also includes a problem you would have to solve right after this one.

Comment: Totally fixed it. Didnt know the ```let``` had to be in the same block as it's ```princ```. Thanks!

Comment: No, the variable NAME has to be used inside the LET body, since it has been defined by the LET.